# How do I print to console the value of LOCAL_LDFLAGS in a make file?

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

I'm trying to debug a problem with my make file. I have appended a number of paths to LOCAL_LDFLAGS, like so:

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L$(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/libs/, $(PRIVATE_LIBRARIES))
```

I would like to print the value of LOCAL_LDFLAGS so that I can debug the issue I am encountering. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
$(info LOCAL_LDFLAGS = $(LOCAL_LDFLAGS))
```

Comment: This almost looks like what I am looking for. But how do I print this to console? I tried echo to no avail.